# Me arroja error en la lista, no reconoce el constructor

Tags: java, android, flutter, ios, dart

> Este es un código que encontré,

> pero he tratado de usar distintos códigos pero se me presenta siempre un error en la lista.

> No se si sea claro mi duda, pero tratare de dar la cantidad de detalle necesaria.

> Estoy tratando de listar elementos de mi base de datos

> Que me los muestre en una lista

> Y tener las opciones de CRUD. para cada elemento de mi lista.

```
class _listPage2State extends State<listPage2> {

  Future<List> obtenerUsuarios() async {
    var url="http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/pedido_flutter/list.php";
    final response= await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
   
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("LISTA"),
      ),
```

> En "lista:snapchot.hasDAta" me lo subraya en rojo

```
      body: FutureBuilder<List> (
        future: obtenerUsuarios(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ElementoLista(
            lista: snapshot.data,
          )
              : Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MenuPage(),
            )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> Al querer instanciar mi clase lista no la reconoce, o no se si se haga distinto ahora, o me falte incorporar algo.

> adicional, ya tengo agregado la dependencia http

```
class ElementoLista extends StatelessWidget {

  final List lista;

  ElementoLista({ required this.lista });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: lista == null ? 0 : lista.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, posicion) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {

              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => MenuPage(
                      index: posicion,
                      lista: lista,
                    ),
                  )
              );
            },

            child: Card(
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text(
                  lista[posicion]['idUsuario']+": "+lista[posicion]['nombre'],
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),

          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Que versión de flutter tienes instalada?

Comment: 3.3.4 es la versión que tengo, en código hay alguna inconsistencia?

Comment: 3.3.6 lo acabe de actualizar

Comment: Lo que logro entender es que el error de lista: snapshot.data te sale subrayado en rojo, es porque no te está detectando el parámetro de la clase ElementoLista, pero lo que no logro entender es por qué no te acepta la variable de tipo List en esa clase

Comment: Si pones el curso encima del código subrayado en rojo que te sale?

Comment: The argument type 'List<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>

Comment: Listo, entonces solo tienes que poner al final "!": lista: snapshot.data!

Comment: Si, funciono. Gracias